# Does Autodesk recommend offline forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Does Autodesk recommends offline forge viewer?

what is advantages of offline forge viewer over online?

I am referring this [tutorial](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample), but struggling with some error as follows:

[image: Error]

if there is any working example of offline forge viewer please drop link here.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Autodesk recommends offline forge viewer?

We are neutral on this - there's no recommendation as to whether to load the model from our service or your own ... it's entirely a matter of your business requirements ...

> what is advantages of offline forge viewer over online?

There's no pros and cons loading the model from our service or yours ... it really on your requirements such as confidentiality, security (of your Forge app tokens/credentials) and network proximity etc ...

The error you ran into suggests the SVF file could not be loaded so check these:

- Viewer only supports http/https and not any other protocols (so URLs starting with `file:///` won't work)
- See your browser's console output for errors
- Make sure you've provided the correct path to the SVF file to Viewer

Post your code if you still have problems so we can look into it...